# Number of equivalence relations on a set with fixed class

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For A={a,b,c,d,e,f}, how much equivalence relations can we get if a,b and c are in relation?

The total is: $\sum_{k=1}^6 S(6,k)$. But since a,b and c are already in the same class, i would say the answer is $\sum_{k=1}^3 S(3,k)$.

I know that answer is not ok, but why exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a,b$ and $c$ are together in one equivalence class, we can think of them as a single object, which I’ll call $x$; the problem then is to count the number of equivalence relations on $A'=\{x,d,e,f\}$. For instance, the equivalence relation on $A'$ whose classes are $\{x,d\}$ and $\{e,f\}$ corresponds to the equivalence relation on $A$ whose classes are $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\{e,f\}$. Thus, you’re simply counting the equivalence relations on a $4$-element set, and you want the Bell number

$$B_4=\sum_{k=0}^4{4\brace k}=\sum_{k=0}^4S(4,k)\;.$$